# For Loop to generate of missing values in R

Tags: r

I want to check the effects of missing values on heart disease data. Now I want to generate 1% to 10% of missing values using the MCAR mechanism. I have been trying to run the code using the for loop but still getting errors. I need a help.

```
p = c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1) #generate missing values 1:10%
nmv = rep(0, length(p))
hd_mcar = rep(0, length(p))

for(i in p){
hd_mcar[i] <- delete_MCAR(heart.ds, length(p)) #creating missing values
nmv[i] <- sum(is.na(hd_mcar)) #checking the number of missing values genereated

}
```

This is the error r normally print out for me:

```
Error in check_delete_args_general(ds, p, cols_mis, n_mis_stochastic) : 
  probabilties in p must be between 0 and 1
```

I want the code to run at the end returning a data frame. This is the code for only one probability of missing values and it runs perfect;

```
#Missing Completely at Random(MCAR)
hd_mcar <- delete_MCAR(heart.ds, 0.05)
sum(is.na(hd_mcar))
```

So I want the above problem to also return the same dataframes but with the appropriate missingness percentages.

Comment: In your perfect code, you pass the probability of missingness as the second argument to`delete_MCAR`.  In your failing code, you pass `length(p)` as the second argument.  `length(p)` is 10, so cannot be a *probability*.  Perhaps that is the problem.  You haven't defined your `delete_MCAR` function or `heart.ds`, so your code is not reproducible.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533980/how-do-i-loop-through-dummy-data-in-r-to-randomly-replace-a-random-amount-of-val/72534136#72534136) is related.